# What is the best way to install .Net Core SDK 2.2 for development

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2019

I am going through a tutorial to create a Razor page App in Visual Studio 2019:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/razor-pages-start?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

On this page it lists the prerequisites:
1) Visual Studio 2019 with the ASP.NET and web development workload
2) .NET Core SDK 2.2 or later

I downloaded the Visual Studio 2019 install so I have that ready to go.
But when I click on the ".NET Core SDK 2.2 or later" link it takes me here:
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/archives

And when I click on that link it takes me here:
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2

And when I click on ".Net Core Downloads" it takes me here:
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core

And finally when I click on .Net Core 2.2 (Current) it takes me here:
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2

Ah finally I am on the  v2.2.6 page but now the installs are split in 2.
1) Build apps - SDK 2.2.401
2) Run apps - Runtime 2.2.6

I have never seen this before, having to install two pieces.

Question number 1: If I just install Visual Studio 2019 will I have everything I need for development?  Or do I need to install .Net Core 2.2.n also.

Question number 2: If I need to install .Net Core 2.2.6 (current) do I need to install both SDK and Runtime separately? And if so is there a single file to install both at the same time anywhere?
Or do I need to install both (for windows):

SDK 2.2.401 - NET Core Installer: x64
Runtime 2.2.6 - ASP.NET Core Installer: x64

I guess I will start experimenting.

Just confusing.  I guess list-sdks would then show 2.2.401 and not 2.2.6.  And then there must be separate list commands for runtime and release?

Yep confusing.

I know preview 3 is out.
They have a note here at the top it is coming out:
.NET Conf 2019
.NET Core 3.0 launches at .NET Conf 2019 September 23-25, a free, virtual developer event. -
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I just install Visual Studio 2019 will I have everything I need
>   for development? Or do I need to install .Net Core 2.2.n also.

When you install VS, you can configure your specific development environment by choosing corresponding [workloads and components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#step-4---choose-workloads) according to your needs. If you want to develop `.net desktop` projects like `winform and wpf`, you should choose `.Net desktop development` workload, and if you only want to develop `Razor Page app`, you just need to install VS2019 with `ASP.NET and web development` workload.

Normal if we choose this workload, vs installer will install `.net framework(4.0 to 4.6) and asp.net core 2.1` for you `by default`. However, there's no single component for .net core SDK 2.2 when installing. So apart from VS with `ASP.NET and web development` workload, we need to manually install the `.net core 2.2` SDK.

> If I need to install .Net Core 2.2.6 (current) do I need to install
>   both SDK and Runtime separately? And if so is there a single file to
>   install both at the same time anywhere? Or do I need to install both
>   (for windows)

As for question2, I never install the sdk in that way. I use another way to download and install the sdk. Here is [the download link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks?utm_source=getdotnetsdk&utm_medium=referral) I use.I think you only need to install this SDK:

[image]

The SDK includes everything you need to **`build and run`** .net core applications while the runtime includes everything you need to **`run`** .net core applications.**The runtime is included in the SDK.** (So you don't need to install the runtime separately)

In summary, to develop razor pages, you need to install VS with `ASP.NET and web development` workload and the SDK mentioned in the picture above. Just do as the document suggests. Hope it helps:)

Comment: Yes.  Runtime included in SDK comment helps.  Makes sense then that developers would only need SDK file.  For clients we would only install Runtime.  The link I eluded to also has the "ASP.NET Core/.NET Core: Runtime & Hosting Bundle" included as well as the sdk and runtime.  Sorry for the low grade question.  I 've been out for 10 months trying to get back to work.  .Net develper since the beginning but had a stroke 10 months ago.  Trying to get back into it now.

Answer (score 0):

I too was confused by this.  When I finished installing ONLY the `SDK .NET Core Installer: x64` (file dotnet-sdk-3.0.100-win-x64.exe) the installer showed this message:

```
The following were installed at: 'C:\Program Files\dotnet'
    • .NET Core SDK 3.0.100
    • .NET Core Runtime 3.0.0
    • ASP.NET Core Runtime 3.0.0
    • .NET Core Windows Desktop Runtime 3.0.0
```

As you can see, only running the SDK installer also installs the runtime, the ASP.NET runtime, and the Desktop runtime. So it's not necessary to install these separately.

TL;DR If you are developer just download the SDK Installer and run that